# `map` method on arrays within an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using nested map on has_many association in following method

```
@trial.treatment_selections
.map { |ts| ts.establishment_methods.map { |em| em.final_establishment.to_f }}
# => [[10.2, 10.1, 10.1], [11.4, 11.4, 10.9]]
```

Here `treatment_selections` has_many `establishment_methods`.

I'm not sure how to get following array:

```
[10.2, 10.1, 10.1, 11.4, 11.4, 10.9]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```
<%= @trial.treatment_selections.flat_map { |ts| ts.establishment_methods.map { |em| em.final_establishment.to_f }} %>
```

Comment: Spot on. Cheers @emaillenin.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flatten method of an Array

```
@trial.treatment_selections
      .map { |ts| ts.establishment_methods.map { |em| em.final_establishment.to_f }}
      .flatten
#=> [10.2, 10.1, 10.1, 11.4, 11.4, 10.9]
```